Detail Page Button redirecting inside Salesforce Organization
Context :
We have created an automated system that allows us to retrieve the ID of each Slack message, "LastSlackMessageId__c", which allows us to complete a field "SlackPermaLink__c".
We wanted to create a detail page button that would redirect the user to the Slack message in question.
The automations work perfectly and the fields LastSlackMessageId__c and SlackPermaLink__c are filled as desired.
The button we created is a detail page button that returns the URL of the SlackPermaLink__c field.
When I click on the button, Salesforce redirects me to the link, but adds the Salesforce organization before the link.
Example :
SlackPermaLink__c = https://XXXXX.slack.com/archives/C079VC9/p146464489?thread_ts=1719857.634079&cid=C079VC9
Link from the button = https://XXXXX.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Case/500SZ00000Brmy0YAB/https%3A%2F%2FXXXXXX.slack.com%2Farchives%2FC07902%2Fp1719418329%3Fthread_ts%3D1719409853.569339%26cid%3DC079EY
Do you know why Salesforce does not redirect me directly to the link entered in the button?
Thank you in advance
SCREEN1 : 
